# NGINX load balance via client subnet

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, subnet

I have 3 frontends with web application in different subnets.

I want to use nginx as load balancer, but I want balance clients via client subnet.

For example:

frontend1 - 1.1.1.10

frontend2 - 1.2.1.10

frontend3 - 1.3.1.10

nginx - 1.1.1.11

Example 1 :

Client (1.1.1.15) connect to web application url (DNS resolve nginx IP) after this Nginx redirect client to frontend1 - 1.1.1.10 in same subnet.

Example 2 :

Client (1.2.1.15) connect to web application url (DNS resolve nginx IP) after this Nginx redirect client to frontend1 - 1.2.1.10 in same subnet.

How to configure this load balancing via NGINX?

Now I have code in nginx confin like this:

```
http {
    upstream myapp1 {
    ip_hash;
        server srv1.example.com;
        server srv2.example.com;
        server srv3.example.com;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        }
    }
}
```

I know NGINX can use if/else construction in config files, but I don't know how to use it with load balancer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you do any research on your own? If so, what did you do? If not, why not?

Comment: I know I can use if/else actions like this -
server {
    if ($remote_addr = 1.2.3.4) {
        some action
    } 
But I don't understand how to use it with load balanser directive